# When is the data layer for Google Analytics fired, or, how can I test my ecommerce data collection script?

Tags: javascript, paypal, google-analytics, e-commerce

I would like to provide Google Analytics ecommerce data for my department and do not know what to do next. I have access to Google Analytics, but not our Google Tag Manager account. I also am not allowed access to anything server-side, or any master pages. Previously, the IS department has told my boss that it was impossible to collect ecommerce data because we use a severely outdated database application that doesn't seem to have any documentation I can find.

I do not believe it is impossible. Considering my limitations, I thought a DOM scraping method would be best, where the transaction details are pushed to the data layer on the thank you pages, after customers are returned from PayPal.

I wrote a script to push this data, but I do not know how to test it with my limited access.

```
window.onload = function(){

var priceString = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTotalPayment').textContent;
var priceString = priceString.slice(1);
var price = parseInt(priceString);

var classSKU = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvConfirmEnrollments_ctrl0_trCourseCombo').textContent;
var classSKU = classSKU.slice(11);

var className = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvConfirmEnrollments_ctrl0_hlTitle').innerHTML;

var classPrice = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTotalPayment').textContent;
var classPrice = classPrice.slice(1);
var classPrice = parseInt(classPrice);

var category;
if (classPrice === 0) {
  category = "Info Session";
}
else {
  category = "Class";
};

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionAffiliation': '',
   'transactionTotal': price,
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': classSKU,
       'name': className,
       'category': category,
       'price': classPrice,
       'quantity': 1
   }]
});
};
```

The biggest thing I'm not sure about is when the datalayer is fired off to Google. I put my script at the end of the head tag but I'm still not sure if the transaction details will actually be pushed into the data layer before it's fired.

My second, more general question, is does anyone know of a way to test this?

Comment: Are you using Universal Analytics or Classic Analytics for your GA tags?

Comment: @vinoaj I'm pretty sure it's all universal analytics since I only see references to analytics.js

Comment: in that case, use the methodology here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

You'll also need to add an `'event':'purchase'` item.

Then set a UA tag in GTM to fire when `event == purchase`, and set UA tag type to Ecommerce.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. How do I add an "'event':'purchase' item"? Is this something I need to add to a script or is it also done in GTM?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to Google Tag Manager you can still ask them to SHARE the preview (debug) URL and test your stuff that way.

Otherwise you can always type `dataLayer` into the chrome console and get in return the parameters (it's a manual way of debugging it)

You can also use [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to check from the console the ecommerce data that Analytics receives.

Comment: The dataLayer is already being successfully populated by my script. To write it, I copied and pasted the HTML from the developer tools while on a thank you page. There's no easy way for me to test the script implemented in the actual server. Do both of these methods require that? Using Google Analytics Debugger I get 'Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization.'

Comment: Those 3 methods are useful when you want to test everything on your side so the access is not required. 
The only last check you can do is to see the transaction data in Analytics, unfortunately if something is wrong in GTM and you don't have access there is not much you can do, can't they install another GTM container and let you work from that?

The outdated DB problem they mention is irrelevant tho, if you scrape correctly (you can retrieve those values with DOM elements directly in GTM and so on) it will work just fine.